# Best resources to help learn bouldering feet & hand placement

Tags: rock-climbing, bouldering

I recently went to a bouldering gym and came across these black (sloper?) rocks on a practically vertical wall. Does anybody have any tips for conquering a wall such as this, or know any good resources to help me better my technique for these unusual sort of placements (especially for footwork)?

[image]

Comment: I have found that personal lessons turbocharge my climbing improvement. I'm sure your gym offers them, and someone who can climb that specific wall can help you.

Comment: Probably. Right now I'm just looking for some basic tips such as: do I lean into the wall, or do I try and hang out with straight arms, what angle should I put my feet and do I just use the ball of my foot or step entirely onto them (for more surface area), should I try and crimp, or should I just have enough body strength to friction my way up the slopes etc. etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have figured it out in the months since your question, but just in case: yes, those are sloper holds, and in my view, you need two things with them:

1. Body positioning that ensures that you stay well below the sloper on which you have your pulling hand(s), with straight arms.
2. Heel hooks, often, and toe hooks, sometimes.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dl-awLKxQBg) will also tell you that you need more shoulder/core strength with slopers than with other holds, which checks out, given the two points above.